# VBA Macros Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm creating a program in Excel that gets the highest and lowest numbers. I get the highest number but the lowest number stays always at 0. Please help me what I'm doing wrong.
This is the screenshot of the numbers I'm using:

[image: Pictue]

This is the Code I created:

```
Sub Code()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim max, min As Long

    For i = 1 To 10

        If Cells(i, 1).Value < min Then
            min = Cells(i, 1).Value
        End If

        If Cells(i, 1).Value > max Then
            max = Cells(i, 1).Value
        End If

    Next i

    Cells(3, 4).Value = min
    Cells(4, 4).Value = max

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `min` variable is defaulted to 0 when it is declared.  Therefore, since none of your values are negative, the `min` variable will remain zero (none of the values are ever less than it).  The `If...Then` statement below will never be true:

```
If Cells(i, 1).Value < min Then
    min = Cells(i, 1).Value
End If
```

You have two options to fix this:

1. Initialize the variable as a high number such as 999
2. Read in the value in the first cell and set it as min's starting point

Comment: Thanks i just set the min = 999 for now ... Thanks again

Comment: You're welcome.  If my answer solved your problem, please flag it as correct (click the check by it).

Comment: I will but i got to wait 7 more minutes

Answer (score 3):

Alternative:

```
max = WorksheetFunction.max(Range("A1:A10"))
min = WorksheetFunction.min(Range("A1:A10"))
```

Comment: Or Application.Min(Range("A1:A10")) and Application.Max(Range("A1:A10"))

Comment: I need it using the min = to some values nut a function